Images from Instagram Basic Display API not rendering on NEXTjs deployed on Vercel?
I've built the project using NextJS (TypeScript + TailwindCSS).
I added a page called Gallery which displays the Instagram Post Feed.
In Local Dev Environment it is working perfectly fine.
But on the production build deployed on Vercel, only captions show and images are showing broken.
I tried added the following configuration to vercel.json file, but it is not working.
{
    "images": {
      "domains": ["scontent.cdninstagram.com", "www.instagram.com"],
      "sizes": [640, 750, 828, 1080, 1200, 1920, 2048, 3840]
    }
}

Code of feed display =>
'use client';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/moving-border';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { RiInstagramFill } from "react-icons/ri";
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

type Props = {
    images: {
        id: string;
        caption: string;
        media_url: string;
        permalink: string;
        media_type: string;
        timestamp: string;
        }[];
}

const FeedDisplay = ({ images } : Props) => {
    const [postsToDisplay, setPostsToDisplay] = useState(12);
    images = images.filter(img => img.media_type !== 'VIDEO');
    const initialPosts = images.slice(0, postsToDisplay);

    const loadMorePosts = () => {
        setPostsToDisplay((prevCount) => prevCount + 12);
      };

  return (
    <>
        <div className='w-full h-full grid grid-cols-12 gap-3'>
          {initialPosts.map(image => (
            <motion.div 
                key={image.id} 
                initial={{ opacity: 0.0, y: 40 }}
                whileInView={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
                transition={{
                    delay: 0.3,
                    duration: 0.8,
                    ease: "easeInOut",
                }}
                className='col-span-6 md:col-span-4 lg:col-span-3 relative group  min-h-[200px] min-w-[200px] aspect-square shadow-lg overflow-hidden'
                
                >
                <Link href={image.permalink} target='_blank'>
                    <Image
                        src={image.media_url}
                        alt={image.caption}
                        fill
                        className='object-cover object-center transition-all duration-1000 group-hover:scale-[1.1]'
                    />
                </Link>
                <div className='text-gray-10 absolute right-[10px] top-[10px]'>
                    <RiInstagramFill />
                </div>
            </motion.div>
          ))}
        </div>

        <Button  
            type='button'
            containerClassName='h-12 mt-10 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50'
            borderClassName='bg-[radial-gradient(var(--bittersweet)_40%,transparent_60%)]'
            className='bg-tekhelet-600 text-gray-10 transition-all duration-700 hover:bg-tekhelet-700'
            onClick={loadMorePosts}
            disabled={postsToDisplay >= images.length}
        >
        {postsToDisplay >= images.length ? 'No more posts' : 'Load more posts'}
        </Button>
    </>
  )
}

export default FeedDisplay

How can I resolve this issue?
